# How does JavaScript [] really work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, associative-array

I'm writing a JavaScript interpreter for extremely resource-constrained embedded devices (http://www.espruino.com), and every time I think I have implemented some bit of JavaScript correctly I realise I am wrong.

My question now is about `[]`. How would you implement one of the most basic bits of JavaScript correctly?

I've looked through the JavaScript spec and maybe I haven't found the right bit, but I can't find a useful answer.

I had previously assumed that you effectively had two 'maps' - one for integers, and one for strings. And the array length was the value of the highest integer plus one. However this seems wrong, according to jsconsole on chrome:

```
var a = [];
a[5] = 42;
a["5"]; // 42
a.length; // 6
```

but also:

```
var a = [];
a["5"] = 42;
a[5]; // 42
a.length; // 6
```

So... great - everything is converted into a string, and the highest valued string that represents an integer is used (plus one) to get the length? Wrong.

```
var a = [];
a["05"] = 42;
a.length; // 0
```

`"05"` is a valid integer - even in Octal. So why does it not affect the length?

Do you have to convert the string to an integer, and then check that when converted back to a string, it matches?

Does anyone have a reference to the exact algorithm used to store and get items in an array or object? It seems like it should be very simple, but it looks like it actually isn't!

Comment: [The standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) says: "*A property name `P` (in the form of a `String` value) is an array index if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(P))` is equal to `P` and `ToUint32(P)` is not equal to `2**32-1`.*".

Comment: If you're writing an interpreter, assumptions shouldn't be used. You should be reading the spec.

Comment: Why don't you use existing, powerful and standard-compliant JS implementations, like V8? What I read at http://www.espruino.com/Performance sounded horrible :-/

Comment: @Bergi V8, like every other JIT compiler, is rather hard to port and not a good fit for resource-constrained devices. Not only is the JIT compiler's output architecture-specific, setting up the memory for that code is also OS-specific. And a JIT compiler practically always uses more memory than a simple interpreter. They also need some time to warm up and become fast. All these make them very ill-suited for obscure devices with few resources.

Comment: Thanks - I did in fact try and find this in the spec before posting, but I must have been looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I do try and follow the spec whenever I can but for a single developer it is a hard task.

Bergi: V8 needs at least 1000x times more memory than Espruino. It may sound horrible to you but unfortunately to get the requirements down that low, compromises have to be made. When the CPU can read every byte in memory in less than 1ms you can afford to waste some CPU in order to be as memory efficient as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the specs said, and was noted by others:

> "A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 2^32-1."

That's explain why in your scenario `"5"` is considered an array index and `"05"` is not:

```
console.log("5" === String("5" >>> 0));
// true, "5" is equal to "5", so it's an index

console.log("05" === String("05" >>> 0));
// false, "05" is not equal to "5", so it's not an index
```

Note: the [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E%3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29) is the shortest way in JS to have a substitute of `ToUint32`, shifting a number by zero.

Comment: Thanks - this also explains the issue with array length, which other answers didn't really address. Thanks for the link to the spec as well DCoder

Answer (score 4):

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

> It's possible to quote the JavaScript array indexes as well (e.g.,
>   years["2"] instead of years[2]), although it's not necessary. The 2 in
>   years[2] eventually gets coerced into a string by the JavaScript
>   engine, anyway, through an implicit toString conversion. It is for
>   this reason that "2" and "02" would refer to two different slots on
>   the years object and the following example logs true:

```
console.log(years["2"] != years["02"]);
```

So with `a["5"]` you are accessing the array while `a["05"]` sets a property on the array object.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are just objects.  That means they can have additional properties which are not considered elements of the array.

If the square bracket argument is an integer, it uses it to perform an assignment to the array.  Otherwise, it treats it as a string and stores it as a property on the array object.

**Edit based on delnan's comment and DCoder's comment, this is how JavaScript determines if it is an appropriate index for an array (versus just a property):**
http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4

Comment: The last part is not particular useful unless you define *what exactly* "an integer" is and what isn't. For example, is "05" an integer and why (not)?

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are also objects.

By doing this

```
a["05"] = 5;
```

You are doing the same thing as:

```
a.05 = 5;
```

**However**, the above will result in a syntax error, as a property specified after a dot cannot start with a number.

So if you do this:

```
a = [];
a["05"] = 5;
```

you still have an **empty array**, but the property of `a` named `05` has the value `5`.

The number `x` [is an array index](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4) if and only if `ToString(ToUint32(x))` is equal to `x` (so in case of `"05"` that requirement is not met).